# problema de execução de código no VisuAlg no Fedora 35

Tags: linux, visualg

Olá, estou com problemas em executar o seguinte código

```
algoritmo "imc"
var
   m,h,imc:real
inicio
   escreva("Insira sua massa (Kg): ")
   leia(m)
   escreva("Insira sua altura (m): ")
   leia(h)
   imc<-m/h^2
   escreval("seu IMC é ",imc:2:2)
   se imc < 18.5 entao
      escreva("Você está leve demais")
   fimse
   se imc > 25 entao
         escreva("Você está pesado demais")
   fimse
   se (imc >= 18.5 e imc <= 25) entao
        escreva("Você está com o peso ideal")
   fimse
   
fimalgoritmo
```

quando vou rodar o programa, aparece esta janela
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

não sei qual é o problema

Comment: Que tipo de problema tu estás tendo? Qual é o erro que precisas corrigir?

Comment: na linha 17, retire o 'imc >= 18.5 e imc <= 25' de dentro do parentese e tente executar o código.

Comment: atualizei a pergunta, coloquei a imagem do resultado da execução do código

Answer (score 0):

consegui resolver o meu problema
eu coloquie cada operador relacional e coloqui dentro de parenteses

ficou assim:

```
algoritmo "imc"
var
   m,a,imc:real
inicio
      escreva("Insira sua altura: ")
      leia(a)
      escreva("Insira seu peso: ")
      leia(m)

      imc<-m/a^2

      escreval("Seu IMC é ",imc:2:2)

      se imc < 18.5 entao
         escreva("Você está leve demais")
      fimse
      se ((imc >= 18.8) e (imc <= 25)) entao
         escreva("Você está dentro do peso ideal")
      fimse
      se imc > 25 entao
         escreva("Você está pesado demais")
      fimse
fimalgoritmo
```